# Prevent abbreviations from echoing on the command line

Tags: key-bindings, abbreviations

If I want to map a key to a certain command and I don't want the command to echo in the command line, I can do the following:

`:nnoremap <silent> <leader>N <... command ...>`

But can the same be done with abbreviations? I didn't see anything relating to this in the manual, so I was wondering if it's even possible to prevent the abbreviation command from appearing in the command line.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, considering you can't even add abbreviations in normal mode? How do you imagine this to work?

Comment: @MartinTournoij I'm sorry, I just realized that my question was confusing after I found the solution to it!. The reason is that I was executing an abbreviation command with `execute`, and it was displaying the abbreviation command in the command line every time it ran. By adding `silent execute` I stopped this behavior. Thanks for you attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get an `abbrev` command to work without displaying it in the command line by wrapping it into a `silent execute "normal! < iabbrev command here >"`. Without `silent`, the command passed to `normal!` will display in the command line, but by putting it into `silent` prevents  any messages from appearing in message history.

Comment: You shouldnt need `normal!` ; `silent execute 'iabbrev <lhs> <rhs>' should do it. But you also don’t need execute unless your building the abbreviation from strings.